# CSS Containing an article with images as page resizes

Tags: css, firefox

I'm working on an RSS reader so I am pulling in HTML from RSS feeds.  I want to display it in my own site, but I am trying to format it so it doesn't break the layout.

In Chrome, it works just fine.  I found a situation where images could be too wide so they would break out of the containing `article` tag when the page was resized.  I fixed that by using:

```
article * {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Firefox, however, will not resize my images to fit the parent container.  The following jsfiddle page shows the behavior.  If you shrink the output frame it doesn't break in Chrome, but in Firefox, the images will break out of the box instead of resizing.

http://jsfiddle.net/CL6rc/12/

How can I get this to work in Firefox or is it even possible?

Comment: I've tried the link you gave, image resizing is working fine in firefox (8.0.1) for me. The image is staying inside the box. What is the version of the firefox you are working on? Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the behavior, and the version of Firefox you are using?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I guess my real code had some `float: left` hanging around.  I couldn't actually reproduce it in jsfiddle (even with the float) so I guess I've solved it but don't know how to show the broken version.  Thanks for checking anyway!

Comment: Oh, CSS typo, now the broken page works: [http://jsfiddle.net/CL6rc/12/](http://jsfiddle.net/CL6rc/12/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had one of the containers set to `float: left`

Removing that property fixed the problem (the original jsfiddle link had the float left out so it did indeed work in Firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle I made for you http://jsfiddle.net/9YvJs/